# How do I change my Edge Loop color from yellow to blue?

Tags: edges

I'm just starting out on Blender and I'm finding the yellow edge loops on the grey object color a bit harsh on the eyes. 
How do I change this so when I use the edge loop shortcut CTRL R, the preview edge loop will be whatever color I decide on?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit** > **Preferences** >**Themes** > **Usere Interface** > **Axis and Gizmo Colors** > **Gizmo Primary**

[image]

Comment: Excellent. Exactly what I'm looking for. Thanks.

Comment: @Kiarian Please mark the answer as accepted (the grey checkmark) if it helped :).